# jqGrid not displaying data (asp.net web service with json)

Tags: jquery, vb.net, jqgrid

I've look through other similar threads and I can't seem to get my jqGrid to display the data that I am trying to bind. The colModal and colNames do came out nicely, but there's no data. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Web Service:

```
Structure JSONObject2
    Public page As String
    Public total As String
    Public records As String
    Public rows As List(Of List(Of String))
End Structure

<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function GetData() As Object
    Dim jsObj As JSONObject2
    jsObj.rows = New List(Of List(Of String))
    jsObj.page = 1
    jsObj.records = 3
    jsObj.total = 3

    If Not IsNothing(Session.Item("DataTable")) Then
        Dim dt As DataTable = Session.Item("DataTable")

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim newrow As New List(Of String)
            For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                    newrow.Add(dr(dc))
            Next
            jsObj.rows.Add(newrow)
        Next

    End If

    Return jsObj
End Function
```

jqgrid declaration:

```
jQuery("#dataGrid").jqGrid({
            jsonReader : {
              root:"rows",
              page: "page",
              total: "total",
              records: "records",
              repeatitems: false,
              id: "0"
           },
            url: 'WebService.asmx/GetData',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "POST",
            ajaxGridOptions: {
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            },
            colNames: [<%= colName %>],
            colModel: [<%= colModal %>],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#dataGrid_Pager',
            sortname: 'name',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "name",
            caption: "JSON Example"
        });
```

I use a normal jquery ajax to request for data.

```
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "WebService.asmx/GetData",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                              alert(JSON.stringify(result));

                        }
                    });
```

data return:

```
{"page":"1","total":"3","records":"3","rows":[["rw_administrator","Reports Administrator","account"],["rw_operator","Reports Operator","account"],["rw_monitor","Reports Monitor","account"]]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manage to solve my own problem after some searching. Below is the corrected code if anyone encountered the same problem in future.

```
 jQuery("#dataGrid").jqGrid({
            jsonReader : {
              root:"rows",
              page: "page",
              total: "total",
              records: "records",
              id: "0" 
           },
            url: 'WebService.asmx/GetData',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "POST",
            ajaxGridOptions: {
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            serializeGridData: function (data) {
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            },
            colNames: [<%= colName %>],
            colModel: [<%= colModal %>],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
           pager: '#dataGrid_Pager',
            sortname: 'name',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "name",
            caption: "JSON Example"
        });
```

However, another problem came out, by using the following:

```
ajaxGridOptions: {
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
```

my postData is empty! Started another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201492/jqgrid-postdata-empty-when-use-with-ajaxgridoptions) on this, hopefully someone got a solution for it.

Thanks!